# Quickest Way To Inset a Link Into an Outlook Message

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hyperlink

I send links to network files very often through outlook. Sometimes 10 at a time. I find it very cumbersome to currently add a Hyperlink into Outlook:

1. Copy network address and Paste into Outlook
2. Copy file name and Past into Outlook
3. Select both in Outlook and Copy
4. Right Click and select inset hyperlink
5. Paste into hyperlink location

This process is about 4 steps to many. I should just be able to drag a file somewhere into Outlook to create a hyperlink. Is there any super tricks that Google doesn't know about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drag and drop the file on the network share with the **right** mouse button. Release within the body of the message and click `Create Hyperlink Here`

[image]

As a bonus, the hyperlink will be [created with the UNC path](https://superuser.com/a/922152/206587).

This will work for single files as well as multiple files, but for multiple files, they will be separated by spaces, not line-breaks.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to David's suggestion, your workflow could be better.

1. Shift-Right click on the file, select "Copy as path",
2. Right click, select insert hyperlink in outlook
3. Paste path

That condenses the first 3 into 1, and works even in places where the Copy as Hyperlink functionality isn't supported.

Answer (score 1):

I found for Outlook 2016, I needed to add ***Link*** to the Ribbon before the ***Right-click*** would display the *Link* option.  Of course, once you add the option to a ribbon, it becomes harder to document how to do it.

```
File|Options|Customize Ribbon|Customize the Ribbon|Tool Tabs|Compose Tools|New Group|Rename|xyz
All Commands|scroll down|Link|Add >>|OK
```

Then when you ***Right-click***, ***Link*** has been added to menu and you can add the link with proper formatting.

Comment: You may be able to make this answer easier to follow by adding screenshots of the process.