# Get shortcut to file from right-click menu - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Is there a small utility that will let you get a link to the current file by right-clicking on it in Windows 7 (x64 Enterprise edition)? If the file is on the network, it can create the link as `\\network_location\filename.xyz`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and right click on the file or folder in Windows Explorer.

[[image: Screenshot of shift click context menu]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZpPy.png)

This will work in Windows Vista and 7. [There are alternatives, including a registry hack, to do this in Windows XP and possibly older versions.](https://superuser.com/questions/27047/copy-full-file-path-in-windows-xp)