# How can I copy a file's path to the clipboard from Windows 7's Explorer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer, clipboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Copy filename to clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/14974/copy-filename-to-clipboard)

I vaguely remember some kind of "Send To" context menu option that accomplished this. Cannot recall which version of Windows.

Right now, the steps I take:

1. Right click file and go to properties
2. Copy file location
3. Paste file location in the target text box
4. Copy the file name
5. Paste file name in target text box
6. Quote the file path if necessary

This is a pain. Is there a better way? I'd prefer not to use any third-party software.

Comment: Side note: I now use [Clip X](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) so that cuts down a couple of steps. Still hope there's a better way.

Comment: Did not see that one. Although mine was limited to Windows 7 while the other person wanted a solution for Windows XP +. Based on that, I'd say keep open for other people to find. Doesn't bother me any though :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click the file.
2. Select **Copy as path**.

Comment: Way better than the solution I was expecting. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @BeamingMel-Bin You're welcome.