# How to copy Windows Explorer file selections and paste filenames as text

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, copy-paste, clipboard, selection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Copy filename to clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/14974/copy-filename-to-clipboard)

#### Windows 7:

How can I select multiple files in [Windows Explorer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer) and get a string of text, listing the file names like I would get if I selected the files from within "open file" window of an application?

For example, if I have a directory that contains 100 [JPEG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) files, and I select 01.jpg, 05.jpg, 10.jpg in Windows Explorer via Ctrl + clicks or Shift + click, how can I get a text string that reads **"** *"01.jpg" "05.jpg" "10.jpg"*  with or without the selected files full path **"** without dragging the selected files to another window?

I've tried copy and pasting into [Notepad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) and [WordPad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPad) and it either pastes the pictures into the application or an empty clipboard.

Answer (score 19):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + right-click -> *Copy as Path* gives you the quoted full paths separated by a newline.

Any decent editor can turn that into a list of filenames only separated by whitespace with a few clicks (for example, find/replace to remove the full path and to replace \n with a space character).

Comment: Thank a lot. That solves my problem . I'm building a macro with Macro Express now i can just insert a command to Shift + right-click on the selection then type alt+a to "Copy as Path" to the clipboard from their i can automatically manipulate the text as i want ....thanks alot you save me alot of clicking and dragging :)

Comment: This does work in Windows 7. But not in Windows XP (it is absent).