# Create Copy-Path Keyboard Shortcut Windows 10

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Looking for a way to copy a file path with a keyboard shortcut. For example, I would like to hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and have the selected file or folder's full path copy to the clipboard.

I am aware that I can right click, hold <kbd>shift</kbd> and select copy path, but I find myself doing this often, so I would like a faster way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for pathcopycopy - https://pathcopycopy.github.io/:)

Comment: Could you please expand on this answer? The software linked appears to provide a GUI modification, doesn't seem to provide a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 26):

On Windows 10, you can use the Quick Access Toolbar on Windows Explorer.

Select the file in question, and in the Home tab in the Ribbon find "Copy Path". Right click and then select "Add to Quick Access Toolbar".

[image: Quick Access Ribbon]

Now you can use the Alt shortcuts built into the Quick Access Toolbar to copy path with one key command. Pressing the alt button will show the number associated with the command. By default it will probably be <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: This answer saved my day.

Answer (score 6):

In Explorer, you can use a keyboard shortcut "chord" to copy it to the clipboard:

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>≣ Menu</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>

[Menu key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key):

[image: Menu Key]

You many also want to check out the various answers provided in this older SU question for some ideas:

- [Copy filename to clipboard](https://superuser.com/questions/14974/copy-filename-to-clipboard)

Comment: Thanks! Do you know where could I find a list of keyboard shortcuts for items IN the context menu? As with 'a'. Or actually show them in the context menu?

Comment: @John Since the context menu changes based on the context it's used in, there will be no official/permanent list.  To see what ones are available, open the context menu with Shift+Menu, and the shortcut key(s) to use in the chord will be the letter that's underlined.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be a keyboard shortcut, but you can show the full path in the folder window.  Just enable it in the Folder Options.

1. Open "Folder Options"
2. Click on the "View" Tab
3. Click the check box that says "Display the full path in the title bar".

Then you can simply click at the top where the folder location is displayed and it will allow you to select it and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy it to the clipboard.

Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Because this answers the question in the expected way, and because I have worked with a handful of even fairly recent laptops that do not have the context menu key, I provide the following suggestion for anyone who happens across this post:

Within the File Explorer menu, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> (you do not have to hold it from this point forward) and then <kbd>H</kbd>, followed by <kbd>C</kbd> and then <kbd>P</kbd> which will select the Copy as Path item from the Home ribbon (see image via link below).

The Home ribbon selected, with 'CP' overlaid on the 'Copy as Path' button:

[image: The Home ribbon selected, with 'CP' overlaid on the 'Copy as Path' button]