# Copy file name (without path) to clipboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to have a keyboard shortcut to write a filename to my clipboard. Currently, I have to hit `F2` to start the rename process, followed by `CTRL+A` to select the whole name and finally `CTRL+C` to copy the name.

Is there an easier way of doing this? Do I need to create an AutoHotkey script to accomplish this?

Comment: see also [How to copy file path to clipboard?](https://superuser.com/q/14974/241386)

Comment: Here is the link: https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/34536-copy-file-names-from-windows-explorer/

Comment: @phuclv yep, it's a dupe. Don't know how I didn't find this when searching... ):